# MILP formulation for minimum set Vertex cover problem

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling

I’m sorry to bother you with this simple question. I would like to model a simple model of the minimum cover vertex set problem. I believe that the original problem is such as

$$
\min \quad \sum_{v\in V} x_v
$$
subject to
$$
x_u + x_v \ge 1 \quad \forall (u,v) \in E 
$$
$x_v$ is a binary variable, which takes value $1$ if  vertex $v$ is included in the minimum set and $0$ otherwise.
I have added another binary variable $z_{uv}$ with the following constraint
$$
\sum_{(u,v)\in E} z_{uv} \ge k    
$$
where $k$ is a parameter and $z_{uv}$ equals $1$ if vertex $v$ is in the set  while vertex $u$ is not a member of the minimum set.

So, $x$ is variable controling the vertices while $z$ controls the edges.

I hope you can help me with modeling the second constraint.

I’m confused about the interaction between if nodes are decided to be in the set (i.e., $x_v = 1$) and the edge connected to it.
P.S the edges are defined as $e=(u,v)$ where $u,v$ are the vertices incident to that edge.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following model on the graph $G=(V,E)$:
$$
\min \quad \sum_{v\in V} x_v
$$
subject to
\begin{align}
x_u + x_v &\ge 1 \quad &\forall (u,v) \in E \\
\sum_{(u,v)\in E} z_{uv} &\ge k \\
z_{uv} &\le x_v \quad &\forall (u,v) \in E\\
z_{uv} &\le 1-x_u \quad &\forall (u,v) \in E\\
x_v&\in \{0,1\} \quad &\forall v \in V\\
z_{uv} &\in \{0,1\}\quad &\forall (u,v) \in E
\end{align}

I believe your question specifically refers to the following constraints:

- $z_{uv} \le x_v \quad \forall (u,v) \in E$ : ensures that when $z_{uv}$ takes value $1$, vertex $v$ is selected and
- $z_{uv} \le 1-x_u \quad \forall (u,v) \in E$ : ensures that when $z_{uv}$ takes value $1$, vertex $u$ is left out

Comment: Thank you @Kuifje so much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Happy to help !

Comment: Dear @Kuifje, I would like to have your help in understanding how E as an edge that links two vertices (u,v) can be modeled to be expressed by z_uv has 1 or 0 and compared to variable x that has only v or u. In other words, I can't get that in Python or Matlab. Please help.

Comment: No problem I can show you the python code, just post it as a new question and i will answer there.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kuifje. I will do that